# Laravel 4 Eloquent one-to-many relations with morph

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm pretty new to Laravel and Eloquent, so this could easily be something trivial but anyways I've been missing a good solution so far. So here's my problem:

I have a main gallery and i want the user to be able to upload any images or videos that he needs into that main gallery and select images/videos from that gallery to be shown elsewhere on the website (basically what I'm doing is centralizing multimedia content all in one place).

Using deduction (with all my poor knowledge of Eloquent) i found this as best solution for me:

```
//Gallery Model
class Gallery extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'gallery';

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function images() {
        return $this->morphMany('Image', 'imageable');
    }

    public function videos() {
        return $this->morphMany('Video', 'videoable');
    }
}

//About Orchestra Model
class OrchestraAbout extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'orchestra_about';

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function images() {
        return $this->morphMany('Image', 'imageable');
    }

    public function videos() {
        return $this->morphMany('Video', 'videoable');
    }
}

//Image Model
class Image extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function imageable() 
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

//Video Model
class Video extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function videoable() 
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

And when inserting into database i simply duplicate the row and only change the imageable_id `/videoable_id` and `imageable_type/videoable_type` to match the `OrchestraAbout` Model.

Anyone here knows of a better solution for this?

Thanks for all the smart answers! Cheers!

Comment: you could use the 

    $OrchestraAboutInstance->uploadable_type 

field to determine what type of file has been uploaded and only create a single relationship. much easier.